# tinymce 4 image plugin data attributes

Tags: javascript, image, tinymce, custom-data-attribute

I'm using tinymce (4.0.6) for my article form.  I've updated the image plugin to support the "title" attribute on the img, and i would like to support the custom data attribute "data-caption", as I'll be using that to put caption text under images in articles.

This is my my updated image plugin.min.js:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("image",function(t){function e(t,e){function n(t,n){i.parentNode.removeChild(i),e({width:t,height:n})}var i=document.createElement("img");i.onload=function(){n(i.clientWidth,i.clientHeight)},i.onerror=function(){n()},i.src=t;var a=i.style;a.visibility="hidden",a.position="fixed",a.bottom=a.left=0,a.width=a.height="auto",document.body.appendChild(i)}function n(e){return function(){var n=t.settings.image_list;"string"==typeof n?tinymce.util.XHR.send({url:n,success:function(t){e(tinymce.util.JSON.parse(t))}}):e(n)}}function i(n){function i(){var t=[{text:"None",value:""}];return tinymce.each(n,function(e){t.push({text:e.text||e.title,value:e.value||e.url,menu:e.menu})}),t}function a(t){var e,n,i,a;e=s.find("#width")[0],n=s.find("#height")[0],i=e.value(),a=n.value(),s.find("#constrain")[0].checked()&&h&&u&&i&&a&&(t.control==e?(a=Math.round(i/h*a),n.value(a)):(i=Math.round(a/u*i),e.value(i))),h=i,u=a}function o(){function e(e){function i(){e.onload=e.onerror=null,t.selection.select(e),t.nodeChanged()}e.onload=function(){n.width||n.height||m.setAttribs(e,{width:e.clientWidth,height:e.clientHeight}),i()},e.onerror=i}var n=s.toJSON();""===n.width&&(n.width=null),""===n.height&&(n.height=null),""===n.style&&(n.style=null),n={src:n.src,alt:n.alt,caption:n.caption,title:n.title,width:n.width,height:n.height,style:n.style},t.undoManager.transact(function(){return n.src?(p?m.setAttribs(p,n):(n.id="__mcenew",t.selection.setContent(m.createHTML("img",n)),p=m.get("__mcenew"),m.setAttrib(p,"id",null)),e(p),void 0):(p&&(m.remove(p),t.nodeChanged()),void 0)})}function l(t){return t&&(t=t.replace(/px$/,"")),t}function r(){e(this.value(),function(t){t.width&&t.height&&(h=t.width,u=t.height,s.find("#width").value(h),s.find("#height").value(u))})}function c(){function t(t){return t.length>0&&/^[0-9]+$/.test(t)&&(t+="px"),t}var e=s.toJSON(),n=m.parseStyle(e.style);m.setAttrib(p,"style",""),delete n.margin,n["margin-top"]=n["margin-bottom"]=t(e.vspace),n["margin-left"]=n["margin-right"]=t(e.hspace),n["border-width"]=t(e.border),s.find("#style").value(m.serializeStyle(m.parseStyle(m.serializeStyle(n))))}var s,d,h,u,g,m=t.dom,p=t.selection.getNode();h=m.getAttrib(p,"width"),u=m.getAttrib(p,"height"),"IMG"!=p.nodeName||p.getAttribute("data-mce-object")?p=null:d={src:m.getAttrib(p,"src"),alt:m.getAttrib(p,"alt"),caption:m.getAttrib(p,"data-caption"),title:m.getAttrib(p,"title"),width:h,height:u},n&&(g={name:"target",type:"listbox",label:"Image list",values:i(),onselect:function(t){var e=s.find("#alt");(!e.value()||t.lastControl&&e.value()==t.lastControl.text())&&e.value(t.control.text()),s.find("#src").value(t.control.value())}});var y=[{name:"src",type:"filepicker",filetype:"image",label:"Source",autofocus:!0,onchange:r},g,{name:"alt",type:"textbox",label:"Image description"},{name:"data-caption",type:"textbox",label:"Caption"},{name:"title",type:"textbox",label:"Title"},{type:"container",label:"Dimensions",layout:"flex",direction:"row",align:"center",spacing:5,items:[{name:"width",type:"textbox",maxLength:3,size:3,onchange:a},{type:"label",text:"x"},{name:"height",type:"textbox",maxLength:3,size:3,onchange:a},{name:"constrain",type:"checkbox",checked:!0,text:"Constrain proportions"}]}];t.settings.image_advtab?(p&&(d.hspace=l(p.style.marginLeft||p.style.marginRight),d.vspace=l(p.style.marginTop||p.style.marginBottom),d.border=l(p.style.borderWidth),d.style=t.dom.serializeStyle(t.dom.parseStyle(t.dom.getAttrib(p,"style")))),s=t.windowManager.open({title:"Insert/edit image",data:d,bodyType:"tabpanel",body:[{title:"General",type:"form",items:y},{title:"Advanced",type:"form",pack:"start",items:[{label:"Style",name:"style",type:"textbox"},{type:"form",layout:"grid",packV:"start",columns:2,padding:0,alignH:["left","right"],defaults:{type:"textbox",maxWidth:50,onchange:c},items:[{label:"Vertical space",name:"vspace"},{label:"Horizontal space",name:"hspace"},{label:"Border",name:"border"}]}]}],onSubmit:o})):s=t.windowManager.open({title:"Insert/edit image",data:d,body:y,onSubmit:o})}t.addButton("image",{icon:"image",tooltip:"Insert/edit image",onclick:n(i),stateSelector:"img:not([data-mce-object])"}),t.addMenuItem("image",{icon:"image",text:"Insert image",onclick:n(i),context:"insert",prependToContext:!0})});
```

when I run it through JS Beautifier it comes out looking like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("image", function (t) {
function e(t, e) {
    function n(t, n) {
        i.parentNode.removeChild(i), e({
            width: t,
            height: n
        })
    }
    var i = document.createElement("img");
    i.onload = function () {
        n(i.clientWidth, i.clientHeight)
    }, i.onerror = function () {
        n()
    }, i.src = t;
    var a = i.style;
    a.visibility = "hidden", a.position = "fixed", a.bottom = a.left = 0, a.width = a.height = "auto", document.body.appendChild(i)
}

function n(e) {
    return function () {
        var n = t.settings.image_list;
        "string" == typeof n ? tinymce.util.XHR.send({
            url: n,
            success: function (t) {
                e(tinymce.util.JSON.parse(t))
            }
        }) : e(n)
    }
}

function i(n) {
    function i() {
        var t = [{
            text: "None",
            value: ""
        }];
        return tinymce.each(n, function (e) {
            t.push({
                text: e.text || e.title,
                value: e.value || e.url,
                menu: e.menu
            })
        }), t
    }

    function a(t) {
        var e, n, i, a;
        e = s.find("#width")[0], n = s.find("#height")[0], i = e.value(), a = n.value(), s.find("#constrain")[0].checked() && h && u && i && a && (t.control == e ? (a = Math.round(i / h * a), n.value(a)) : (i = Math.round(a / u * i), e.value(i))), h = i, u = a
    }

    function o() {
        function e(e) {
            function i() {
                e.onload = e.onerror = null, t.selection.select(e), t.nodeChanged()
            }
            e.onload = function () {
                n.width || n.height || m.setAttribs(e, {
                    width: e.clientWidth,
                    height: e.clientHeight
                }), i()
            }, e.onerror = i
        }
        var n = s.toJSON();
        "" === n.width && (n.width = null), "" === n.height && (n.height = null), "" === n.style && (n.style = null), n = {
            src: n.src,
            alt: n.alt,
            caption: n.caption,
            title: n.title,
            width: n.width,
            height: n.height,
            style: n.style
        }, t.undoManager.transact(function () {
            return n.src ? (p ? m.setAttribs(p, n) : (n.id = "__mcenew", t.selection.setContent(m.createHTML("img", n)), p = m.get("__mcenew"), m.setAttrib(p, "id", null)), e(p), void 0) : (p && (m.remove(p), t.nodeChanged()), void 0)
        })
    }

    function l(t) {
        return t && (t = t.replace(/px$/, "")), t
    }

    function r() {
        e(this.value(), function (t) {
            t.width && t.height && (h = t.width, u = t.height, s.find("#width").value(h), s.find("#height").value(u))
        })
    }

    function c() {
        function t(t) {
            return t.length > 0 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(t) && (t += "px"), t
        }
        var e = s.toJSON(),
            n = m.parseStyle(e.style);
        m.setAttrib(p, "style", ""), delete n.margin, n["margin-top"] = n["margin-bottom"] = t(e.vspace), n["margin-left"] = n["margin-right"] = t(e.hspace), n["border-width"] = t(e.border), s.find("#style").value(m.serializeStyle(m.parseStyle(m.serializeStyle(n))))
    }
    var s, d, h, u, g, m = t.dom,
        p = t.selection.getNode();
    h = m.getAttrib(p, "width"), u = m.getAttrib(p, "height"), "IMG" != p.nodeName || p.getAttribute("data-mce-object") ? p = null : d = {
        src: m.getAttrib(p, "src"),
        alt: m.getAttrib(p, "alt"),
        caption: m.getAttrib(p, "data-caption"),
        title: m.getAttrib(p, "title"),
        width: h,
        height: u
    }, n && (g = {
        name: "target",
        type: "listbox",
        label: "Image list",
        values: i(),
        onselect: function (t) {
            var e = s.find("#alt");
            (!e.value() || t.lastControl && e.value() == t.lastControl.text()) && e.value(t.control.text()), s.find("#src").value(t.control.value())
        }
    });
    var y = [{
            name: "src",
            type: "filepicker",
            filetype: "image",
            label: "Source",
            autofocus: !0,
            onchange: r
        },
        g, {
            name: "alt",
            type: "textbox",
            label: "Image description"
        }, {
            name: "data-caption",
            type: "textbox",
            label: "Caption"
        }, {
            name: "title",
            type: "textbox",
            label: "Title"
        }, {
            type: "container",
            label: "Dimensions",
            layout: "flex",
            direction: "row",
            align: "center",
            spacing: 5,
            items: [{
                name: "width",
                type: "textbox",
                maxLength: 3,
                size: 3,
                onchange: a
            }, {
                type: "label",
                text: "x"
            }, {
                name: "height",
                type: "textbox",
                maxLength: 3,
                size: 3,
                onchange: a
            }, {
                name: "constrain",
                type: "checkbox",
                checked: !0,
                text: "Constrain proportions"
            }]
        }
    ];
    t.settings.image_advtab ? (p && (d.hspace = l(p.style.marginLeft || p.style.marginRight), d.vspace = l(p.style.marginTop || p.style.marginBottom), d.border = l(p.style.borderWidth), d.style = t.dom.serializeStyle(t.dom.parseStyle(t.dom.getAttrib(p, "style")))), s = t.windowManager.open({
        title: "Insert/edit image",
        data: d,
        bodyType: "tabpanel",
        body: [{
            title: "General",
            type: "form",
            items: y
        }, {
            title: "Advanced",
            type: "form",
            pack: "start",
            items: [{
                label: "Style",
                name: "style",
                type: "textbox"
            }, {
                type: "form",
                layout: "grid",
                packV: "start",
                columns: 2,
                padding: 0,
                alignH: ["left", "right"],
                defaults: {
                    type: "textbox",
                    maxWidth: 50,
                    onchange: c
                },
                items: [{
                    label: "Vertical space",
                    name: "vspace"
                }, {
                    label: "Horizontal space",
                    name: "hspace"
                }, {
                    label: "Border",
                    name: "border"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        onSubmit: o
    })) : s = t.windowManager.open({
        title: "Insert/edit image",
        data: d,
        body: y,
        onSubmit: o
    })
}
t.addButton("image", {
    icon: "image",
    tooltip: "Insert/edit image",
    onclick: n(i),
    stateSelector: "img:not([data-mce-object])"
}), t.addMenuItem("image", {
    icon: "image",
    text: "Insert image",
    onclick: n(i),
    context: "insert",
    prependToContext: !0
})
});
```

I have this in my tinymce initialization:

```
extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|data-caption]"
```

The title attribute is working as expected, but the data-caption attribute gets removed when the image dialog is submitted.  If I check in the Tools -> Source Code box, the title attribute exists on the resulting img tag, but the data-caption does not.

I think this may have something to do with parts of the function that pass the value of the attribute around such as the line caption: n.caption,.  I did this, as I did not think that data-caption would evaluate correctly as a variable name here.

Has anyone out there tried putting a data attribute on an image through the image plugin in tinymce 4?  Or is there another way I can get the data-caption attribute onto the img tag (short of editing in the source code window)?  I want this to be easy to use for content authors (the whole point of using tinymce), and I've had some great success at writing other custom functions, but this one hang up has me stumped.

Thanks ahead of time!